# Macro not executing function

Tags: c++, windows, macros

I have a macro, and i use it this way:

```
int GL = 0;
GL = GetLastError();
DEBUG_MESSAGE( ERR, "RegOpenKeyEx failed. Error code = '%u'. Error description = '%s'", GL, GetErrorText( GL ) );
```

The function `GetErrorText` returns a `char *`, which is the corresponding errortext belonging to the error code.

The problem is, that when i call my macro, it won't call `GetErrorText` function.
The output will be this : `RegOpenKeyEx failed. Error code = '5'. Error description = ''`

The Macro is defined this way:

```
#define DEBUG_MESSAGE( Type, debug_message, ... ) { _debugLog.message( Type, debug_message, ##__VA_ARGS__ ); }
```

And this is the function what the macro calls:

```
void log::message( int Type, const char * message, ... )
    {
        char MessageExpanded[ 2048 ] = { 0 };
        va_list args;
        int len;

        write_indentation();

        memset( Message, 0, sizeof( Message ) );
        memset( MessageExpanded, 0, sizeof( MessageExpanded ) );

        va_start( args, message );

        len = _vscprintf( message, args ) + 1; // _vscprintf doesn't count terminating '\0'

        vsprintf_s( Message, len, message, args );

        va_end( args );

        sprintf( MessageExpanded, "%s %s", Spaces, Message );
        LOG( MessageExpanded, context.c_str(), "", Type, CurrentFileName );

    }//log::message
```

Is there a way to solve this somehow?

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**

```
char * GetErrorText( DWORD dwLastError )
{
DEBUG_METHOD( INFO );
DEBUG_MESSAGE( INFO, "Argument1 = '%d'", dwLastError );

HMODULE hModule = NULL; // default to system source
LPSTR MessageBuffer;
DWORD dwBufferLength;
char Error[ SMALL ] = { 0 };
char * ErrorMsg = NULL;

DWORD dwFormatFlags = FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM;

// If dwLastError is in the network range, load the message source.
if ( dwLastError >= NERR_BASE && dwLastError <= MAX_NERR )
{
    hModule = LoadLibraryEx( TEXT( "netmsg.dll" ), NULL, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE );
    if ( hModule != NULL ) dwFormatFlags |= FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE;
}

// Call FormatMessage() to allow for message text to be acquired from the system or from the supplied module handle.
if ( dwBufferLength = FormatMessageA(
                                      dwFormatFlags,
                                      hModule,                                     // module to get message from (NULL == system)
                                      dwLastError,
                                      MAKELANGID( LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT ), // default language
                                      ( LPSTR )&MessageBuffer,
                                      0,
                                      NULL
                                    )
    )
{
    memset( Error, 0, sizeof( Error ) );
    //printf( "\n%s", MessageBuffer );
    sprintf( Error, "%s", MessageBuffer );
    ErrorMsg = Error;

    // Free the buffer allocated by the system.
    LocalFree( MessageBuffer );
}

// If we loaded a message source, unload it.
if ( hModule != NULL ) FreeLibrary( hModule );

return ErrorMsg;

}//GetErrorText
```

Comment: Don't you think it kind of matters exactly how the macro is defined?

Comment: How is `GL` declared?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Sorry, you are right, i forgot to post that.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield: GL is an int declared. But this should be "theoretically" irrelevant. The `GetErrorText` function works fine. It won't work with the macro only.

Comment: Show us `GetErrorText()` - maybe it returns something that is no longer valid by the time `_debugLog.message()` is called.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: I posted `GetErrorText()` too.

Comment: Just as @MichaelBurr suggested: you are returning a pointer to a local variable. The pointer becomes invalid as soon as the function returns. It may still appear to work as long as code that uses it just happens to not scribble over that portion of the stack. Apparently, `log::message` does so scribble.

Comment: Remove the ## before \_\_VA_ARGS\_\_

Comment: Note also that you are using `args` twice, which is UB. After calling `_vscprintf`, you need to `va_end(args); va_start(args, message)` to get `args` to point to the first `...` parameter again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetErrorText()` is returning a pointer to a local buffer:

```
char Error[ SMALL ] = { 0 };
```

So the pointer it returns is invalid by the time `_debugLog.message()` is called.

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but how do i return it correctly?

Comment: @kampi, you could make `Error` `static`, but better would be to return a `std::string`.